# Gradle Error when try to add dependency for Zxing scanner

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-3.0

I tried to add a dependency "me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9.8" for the barcode scanner functionality. It populates  Gradle error as given in image

[click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22Bte.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because this library uses the old version `com.android.support` libs.

Try do this:

```
implementation ("me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9.8") {
    exclude group: "com.android.support"
}
```