# Gradle gives compatibility error when adding firebase

Tags: android, gradle, error-handling, libraries, mixing

So, i just created a new project, and before adding any new libraries or anything, i just added the firebase library, and as soon as i synced the gradle it gives me an error saying mixing android libraries can cause problems at appcompat library.

[image: Image that shows the error]

What am i doing wrong here ? why am i getting this error and how do i get rid of it ?

Here is the source code to my gradle file :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 28
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.femindharamshi.codifyadmin"
            minSdkVersion 21
            targetSdkVersion 28
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        } }

    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'

    }

    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53002727/9060113). And just need to do this:

```
implementation ('com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4') {
    exclude group: "com.android.support"
}
```

Comment: Which version of `gms` plugin do you use?

Answer (score 1):

You have to check/fix dependency conflicts,

- `./gradlew androidDependencies` Or `./gradlew app:dependencies`
- Then you will see modules that duplicated among dependencies with different versions.

**Solutions**

1. Force solution:

   ```
   //force a resolution

   configurations.all {
     resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'
   }
   ```
2. Exclude duplicated module

   ```
   //excluding a module!

   implementation ("com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0") {
      exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-media-compat'
   }
   ```

**Update** Force **Support libs**

```
ext {
    supportLibVersion = '28.0.0'
}

dependencies {
    // ... Other dependencies 
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportLibVersion"
    implementation ("com.android.support:support-v4:$supportLibVersion"){
        force = true
    }
    implementation ("com.android.support:exifinterface:$supportLibVersion"){
        force = true
    }
}
```

Comment: if i do the option 2, the error comes on
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'

tho i dont know what that is for

Comment: @UrvikShah check my answer update, with **Force Support libs** solution, Hope that will fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add this implementation :

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'
```

Explanation:
 You can see in the error that there are different library versions you are currently using. In the part after examples it's showing you which one. Although you may think you are not using it. You are using it indirectly with the main libraries. So you have to explicitly upgrade libraries if there is a lower subversion

Answer (score 0):

add this line above your `appcompat` dependency

```
//noinspection GradleCompatible
```

Comment: This is not a solution. It's only avoiding the problem

Comment: i was facing the same issue. dong this helps for me.

Comment: Yes and you might face bugs while running you app. It's must to have the support libraries of same version.

Comment: Read my answer. Add all the implementations the studio is suggesting you to with the latest version. It will solve your problem

Comment: it's problem in android new version. No matter what dependency you use, it will give you that error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182663/discussion-between-jawad-malick-and-arahasya).

Comment: @JawadMalick check my answer for fixing dependency conflicts,